# Android OpenGL Debug: Posting Custom Message Strings

Tags: android, debugging, opengl-es

In Android, when using>

```
glSurfaceView.setDebugFlags(GLSurfaceView.DEBUG_LOG_GL_CALLS);
```

OpenGL posts a number of useful error messages like these>

```
07-21 20:48:47.910: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(5052): glGenTextures(1, [0, 0], 1) returns {
07-21 20:48:47.920: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(5052):  [1] = 1
07-21 20:48:47.920: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(5052): };
07-21 20:48:47.920: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(5052): glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1);
07-21 20:48:47.920: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(5052): glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
07-21 20:48:47.920: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(5052): glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

Is there a built in way to send a message to the same eclipse android debugging output window (in this case filtering on the tag GLSurfaceView)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is just to use the standard logger with the correct tag, so in this case it would be>

Log.v("GLSurfaceView","Custom Error String");